# snap sparql to retrieve data property value

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

I had a new problem now when using snap sparql.
oke, i had 2 class, that is `resep_makanan` which is food name , `bahan_makanan` which is food source.
and i linked those 2 classes using data_property `memiliki_bahan` and at each food source i linked with annotation property `data_memiliki_bahan`.
when using standard SPARQL

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX :<http://www.semanticweb.org/astrid/ontologies/2019/5/mpasiv2#>

SELECT ?resep_makanan ?bahan_makanan  ?value
WHERE { 
?bahan_makanan :data_memiliki_bahan ?memiliki_bahan.
?resep_makanan ?memiliki_bahan ?value.
FILTER regex(str(?resep_makanan),"pure_alpukat")
}
```

i get what i want, but when im using snap sparql with exact same code, it didnt work, how should i write it using snap sparql?
in snap sparql i get this error :
[please click here to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyyjR.png)

Comment: one of the limitations of Snap SPARQL plugin is that predicate variables have to be typed, i.e. it needs another triple pattern which denotes the type of the property, so either object property or data property. (and maybe also annotation property. So, you should wrap it in `UNION` clauses, e.g. `{?resep_makanan ?memiliki_bahan ?value. ?memiliki_bahan rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
FILTER regex(str(?resep_makanan),"pure_alpukat") } UNION {?resep_makanan ?memiliki_bahan ?value. ?memiliki_bahan rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .
FILTER regex(str(?resep_makanan),"pure_alpukat") }`

Comment: could probably simplified more if needed.

Comment: its still doesnt work... T.T

Comment: show the query you're using as well as sample data. I can't redo all the stuff to check on my machine. please lookup the term MWE

Comment: how can i do it?@UninformedUser

Comment: how can you do what? without providing sample data, I'm not able to check on my machine and I'm just too lazy to generate my own sample data now. by the way, it's still not clear what your overall goal is. Sometimes, you use Protege, in the next question you're asking about OWL API.