# Sparql Query for every Individual with specific label

Tags: sparql, protege

I would like to query for every individual in my ontology with a label, which contains a specific string ("PK1"). Then I would like to see every property an value that those individuals have. I tried this code:

```
SELECT ?Probe ?Property ?Value
WHERE
{
         ?Probe ?Property ?Value.
         ?Probe rdfs:label ?Name.
         FILTER(STRENDS(?Name, "PK1"))
}
```

However it marks the Variable ?Property in Line 4 as wrong:

> Expected one of: VARIABLE, rdfs:subClassOf, etc.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: The query looks fine and works e.g. on Wikidata’s endpoint. How/where do run this query?

Comment: I use the Snap Sparql Plugin for Protege

Comment: This seems to be a (very weird, I would say) limitation of Snap. See issue [Variables are not allowed as predicates](https://github.com/protegeproject/snap-sparql-query/issues/9), and related question [snap sparql to retrieve data property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61052478/19579546)

Comment: there is no need to use Snap SPARQL plugin as long as you don't need some kind of inference. So, just run the query in the SPARQL tab and it will work. If you need inference and still want to stick to Protege, export all inferred axioms and load the  materialized ontology again into Protege, then use the SPARQL tab instead of Snap SPARQL.

Comment: Two notes (even if they're not the cause of the problem): 1. The filter you're using only finds values that *end* with "PK1", not every value that *contains* "PK1", as you said in the question. For containment, use [**CONTAINS**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains). 2. Consider adding whitespace between triple patterns and punctuation.  I.e., do `?s ?p ?o .` instead of `?s ?p ?o.` While it doesn't make a difference here with variables, if the object were an IRI, it could.  E.g., `?s ?p ex:object.` is not the same as `?s ?p ex:object .`  (I could be wrong on this point.)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Unfortunately "STRENDS" doesn't work in the regular SPARQL Tab in protege hence I switched to Snap SPARQL in the first place... Seems weird to me that a variable as a predicate is impossible, shouldn't this restrict a lot of use cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my Question. Like Stefan - brox IT-Solutions pointed out, the Problem is a limitation of the Snap Sparql Plugin for Protege. However the Query works if you define the Variable of the predicate. The following code works for me:

```
SELECT ?Probe ?Property ?Value
WHERE
{
    ?Property a owl:ObjectProperty .
    ?Probe ?Property ?Value .
    ?Probe rdfs:label ?Name .
    FILTER(STRENDS(?Name, "PK1"))
}
```

As i said as long as the Variable ?Property is defined as a ObjectProperty or DatatypeProperty it works.

Thank you for your ideas!